# Hugo - data is not being passed into the iteration

Tags: html, go, hugo

I have this segment of code where I want to iterate my

elements within
layouts/partials/homepage/section_2

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                {{ range .topics.navitems }}
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    {{ with .title }}
                    <button class="nav-link" id="{{ .id }}-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#{{ .id }}-tab-pane"
                        type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ .id }}-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">{{ . }}</button>
                    {{ end }}
                </li>
                {{ end }}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this segment within my index.html
layouts/index.html

```
{{define "main"}}
{{partial "homepage/section_1.html"}}
{{ with .Site.Data.home.topics}}
{{partial "homepage/section_2.html"}}
{{end}}
{{partial "homepage/section_3.html"}}
{{partial "homepage/section_4.html"}}
{{partial "homepage/section_5.html"}}
{{end}}
```

And these are my data within the tabs.yaml
data/tabs.yaml

```
enabled : true
id : "topics"

content : 
  title : "Browse Topics"
  navitems : 
    - id : "marketing"
      title : "Our Services"
      url : "/services" 

    - id : "design"
      title : "Why Us?"
      url : "/whyus"

    - id : "finance"
      title : "About Us"
      url : "/aboutus"

    - id : "music"
      title : "Properties"
      url : "/properties"

    - id : "education"
      title : "Education"
      url : "/education"
```

However, my code seems to be unable to access the data within the topics.yaml.

I've gone through many youtube videos to try and look for a solution, even with `$var := ...` At this point I'm kinda bummed out and cannot tell what I am doing wrong

Comment: Pass `.` to the partial.

Comment: thanks, it took me like 6 hours of figuring what's going on :')